# Citrus framework flightbooking

Tags: testing, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I am trying to implement the Flightbooking-sample using CitursFramwork ,the link is : 
https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-flightbooking

And I am still new for the framework , The steps I did are(using mac os) :

1-run the activemq

2-run the jetty:run from the sample-bakery .

3-using intllijIdea open the sample-bakery and run the test case . 
Every time my test case is failed and I got the following :

```
ActionTimeoutException: Action timeout while receiving message from channel 'royalAirlineServer.inbound'
    at com/consol/citrus/samples/flightbooking/FlightBookingIT(receive:57-90)
```

4-I tried to change the timeout but I still get the same error .

Please can anyone explain to me what is the timeout , and where is the wrong in my steps ?

Note:Only one time using Terminal the test case is pass using :

```
mvn clean install -Dembedded=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply mixing different sample projects here. You start the infrastructure of the bakery sample while executing the tests of the flightbooking sample. Both samples do work with totally different endpoints and domains.

Please stay within a sample project when starting infrastructure and test cases.